How to bind parameters with yii2 CreateCommand
When i run this code:
 $params = [':idCollection' => $idCollection, ':idBlock' => $idBlock];
            //dd($params);
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('collectionxblock', [
                'id_collection' => ':idCollection',
                'id_block' => ':idBlock',
            ])->bindValues($params)->execute();

I get this error:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
does not match number of tokens The SQL being executed was: INSERT
INTO collectionxblock (id_collection, id_block) VALUES (0, 0)
How can i bind Parameters with insert query ?


You don't need to explicitly create params and bind them when using query builder or methods like yii\db\Command::insert() or yii\db\Command::update(). The framework will take care of params.
You only need to pass columns and values as array:
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('collectionxblock', [
    'id_collection' => $idCollection,
    'id_block' => $idBlock,
])->execute();

Methods that works with params are available if you want to or need to write SQL query yourself. For example:
Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
    'INSERT INTO collectionxblock (id_collection, id_block) VALUES (:idCollection, :idBlock)'
)->bindValues($params)
    ->execute();


O, i've read something in the docs but for me it's not clear, thank you for the explanation
